# mongodb One-to-Many Relationships with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb

There is an entity called `«offer»`. It has many keywords. In order to avoid M:M relation (an offer may have many keywords and keywords my have many offers), I keep all keywords as embedded documents:

```
offers: {
    title
    …
    country_id,
    dateCreated,
    keyWords: [{keyword1, keyword2, ...}]
    ...
  }
```

There will be a search based on these keywords. When an offer is created, user can add keywords, which are autocompleted if already exist or added if they are new.

And the question is:

> How do I update titles for keywords if they change? Ex. the user
>   mistyped a keyword and moderator corrects it. Or there are several
>   keywords pointing to the same entity and moderator decides to delete
>   them and leave only one changing his title as well. And there may be
>   thousands of offers sharing the same keyword?

One more issue:

> I need to populate the autocompleter with existing keywords. Do I have
>   to keep them also in a separate “table”?

What is the correct way?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question,

You can use [array operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) to achieve this goal. It requires two operations unfortunately.

1. $pull to remove the old value
2. #push to add in the new value.

As for the 2nd question, if you're going to index the keywords field, you can use distinct operator to retrieve list of keywords.

```
db.offer.insert({title: "Hello", keywords: ["one", "five"]});
db.offer.insert({title: "World", keywords: ["one", "three"]});
db.offer.distinct("keywords");
[ "one", "three", "five"]
```

If you don't have index or the collection is too huge, maintaining the list of keywords in a separate collection/document may be an option.

Comment: > you can use distinct operator to retrieve list of keywords - you mean I can create a list of keywords for autocompleter right from the offers keywords?

Comment: The only mandatory index in mongodb is the "_id" field. All other fields, whether to index or not, it should depend on your query pattern. If you have frequent query against the field, then better index it. If only occasionally, probably it's not worthwhile indexing it.

Comment: As for the auto-complete of keywords, you'd better test it out whether you should purely rely on the distinct operator. If your collection is big, and you don't require very timely reflection of keywords available, you may consider caching them and periodically update the cache by using the distinct operator.

Comment: what do you mean > caching them? Placing them into separate collection?

Comment: Cache is just a generic term to put thing into memory for fast retrieval. You can put into your application's memory set or use an in-memory db like Redis.